# How to find : Range of $\cos(\cos x) $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

How to find : Range of $\cos(\cos x) $

My approach :

Since $-1 \leq \cos x \leq 1$ we get

$\cos(-1) \leq \cos(\cos x) \leq \cos(1)$

Is it correct? please suggest.

Can we use the above method to find the range of $\cos(\cos(\cos(\cos(\cos x))))$

Comment: This is not quite correct, since $\cos(-1)=\cos(1)$, the range you have found is made of one point ! The basics in this kind of question is to check the domains where $\cos$ is increasing or decreasing.

Comment: You're implying that the cosinus is increasing on $[-1,1]$, which is false.

Answer (score 3):

The cosine function has a turning point at $x=0$ and by inspection or otherwise this is a maximum. So the range you want is

$$\cos(-1)=\cos(1)\le\cos(\cos(x))\le\cos(0)=1$$

Answer (score 1):

the range is $R=\{\cos x: 0 \leq x \leq 1\}$

Comment: Is it $0 \leq cosx \leq 1 \Rightarrow $cos0 \leq cos(cosx) \leq cos1$ Therefore range is $[1, cos1]$ ???

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that 
$$-1<\cos x<1$$
But cosine is a is an even function so $\cos(x) = \cos -x$, so this means that the outer cosine only gets values between -1 and 1, but as it is even it translates to just 0 to 1. So the value it all can take is  1 to $\cos 1$
$$\cos \cos x \in[\cos 1,1]$$

Answer (score 0):

Range is $\cos 1\leq cos(cosx)\leq 1\}$

Comment: and what about  range of $cos(cos(cos(cosx))))$

Comment: Obviously it should be $\cos(cos(cos (1)))\leq cos(cos(cos(cosx))))\leq cos(cos(1))\}$